# UGUI canvas and NGUI panel overlap issue - Set Sorting Order

Tags: unity, gui, ngui, ugui

I have a **NGUI Panel** and a **UGUI (Unity UI) panel**. All are working fine but there is a small problem. When I open the NGUI panel meanwhile my GUI panel is also open, then NGUI panel appears behind the UGUI. Is there any way available that I combine both GUIs sorting orders so that I **should display the NGUI panel on top of the UGUI panel**?

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid mixing two different UI systems in your game in the first place?

Comment: You mean either i use NGUI or UGUI? No, it is not possible. There are already several canvases and one main gui title bar is built on NGUI.